Handling Missing Groups in Stratified Sampling for Weighted Mean Calculation
I conducted a statistical survey using a stratified sample to measure the knowledge of Italian students on a specific topic. The population was stratified according to the following categories: Area (Urban and Rural), Gender (Male, Female, and Other), Zone (North, South, and Center), and Type of School (High School, Technical, and Professional). This results in 2 * 3 * 3 * 3 = 54 group combinations.
However, some groups have no responses, which distorts the weight estimation and, consequently, the weighted mean of the scores. The weight of each unit is calculated as the reciprocal of the sample size of the group. I would like to know how to handle groups with no responses to obtain correct estimates.
Additionally, the “Other” category in Gender is represented by only 8 units (~2% of the sampled population). How should I handle this case?
Data simulation if could help you (language R):

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Data simulation
set.seed(42)
data <- data.frame(
  Region = sample(c("North", "Center", "South"), 300, replace = TRUE),
  Area = sample(c("Urban", "Rural"), 300, replace = TRUE),
  Gender = sample(c("Male", "Female", "Other"), 300, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.49, 0.49, 0.02)),
  Type = sample(c("High School", "Technical", "Professional"), 300, replace = TRUE),
  Score = runif(300, 60, 100)
)

# missing category
data <- data %>%
  filter(!(Region == "North" & Area == "Urban" & Type == "Professional"))

# Check and complete missing groups
data_complete <- data %>%
  group_by(Region, Area, Gender, Type) %>%
  summarise(
    size = n(),
    weight = if_else(size == 0, 0, 1 / size)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(Region, Area, Gender, Type, fill = list(size = 0, weight = 0))

# Groups missing
data_complete %>%
  filter(size == 0)


Please tell us more about the nature of the nonresponse: what causes it and why are you not modeling it?

Thank you for your question! The nonresponse in our survey is due to certain schools not participating in the project. Unfortunately, no replacements were selected for these non-responding schools. A third party conducted the sampling design, and we are working within the constraints of that design.

That's important, because you should be concerned about the prospect that non-response and survey results might be related.  What if (to give one speculative example) schools that believe they are likely to score low will elect not to participate?

Thank you for pointing that out! In our case, the nonresponse is primarily due to bureaucratic issues rather than an anticipation of low scores. The schools that chose not to participate did so because of administrative hurdles, not because of their expectations regarding performance. However, the omission of these observations does create challenges in accurately attributing the scores, as it affects the weight estimation and the overall weighted mean of the survey results.

There is no weight estimation to be done: those schools simply aren't part of the study.  You must assume nonresponse is independent of results and you must limit your conclusions to the subpopulation of schools that would respond to such a survey if asked.

I understand your point, but the challenge lies in constructing the weights correctly. To evaluate factors such as Gender, weights must be equally balanced across each Region, Type of School, and Zone. The absence of responses from certain schools disrupts this balance and makes it difficult to achieve an accurate and fair estimation.
Without addressing these nonresponses, our weighted estimates for subpopulations become skewed, complicating the analysis.

The point is that you can't do the intended analysis.  You haven't any data from the refusal schools, so the best you can do is attempt to draw inferences about all other schools.  You haven't any statistical basis for drawing inferences about any subpopulation that includes any refusal schools.
